# Finding correct NPM checksum

Tags: node.js, npm

I got two projects where `gulp-sourcemaps` is used. It has a dependency to `debug-fabulous` which has a dependency to `lazy-debug-legacy`.

On my machine the `npm install` on both projects run just fine.

On another machine project A runs fine, project B has a checksum issue:

> sha1-U3cWwHduTPeePtG2IfdljCkRsbE= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: 
>   wanted sha1-U3cWwHduTPeePtG2IfdljCkRsbE= but got sha1-
>   gswqb03PNvrPDHp5RoV7/2KCisc=. (3612 bytes)

When I look at `project-lock.json` from **project A** it says:

```
"lazy-debug-legacy": {
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lazy-debug/-/lazy-debug-0.0.3.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-gswqb03PNvrPDHp5RoV7/2KCisc=",
  "dev": true
},
```

When I look at `project-lock.json` from **project B** it says:

```
"lazy-debug-legacy": {
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lazy-debug/-/lazy-debug-0.0.3.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha1-U3cWwHduTPeePtG2IfdljCkRsbE=",
  "dev": true
},
```

How can I find out which is the correct checksum?

How can my machine succeed installing both projects when the given checksums are obviously in conflict to each other?

Comment: I meanwhile got rid of the issue by upgrading `gulp-sourcemaps` to `2.6.4` where we have no dependency to `lazy-debug-legacy`. But the question *How can I find out which is the correct checksum?* remains.